# How to modify rows in tables in HTML language

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I have this code

```
<html>
<head>
<title> trans </title>
<body>
<style>
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
width: 900px;
margin: auto;
}
h3{
text-align: center;
margin-top: 20px;    
}
</style>
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  
$q = " SELECT * FROM `degree_plan` LEFT JOIN courses ON
degree_plan.course_number=courses.course_number
where major='COE'"; 

$result = mysqli_query($con , $q) ;
if($result){
   echo "<br />";
   echo "<table>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<th>courses</th>";
   echo "<th>term_no</th>";
   echo "</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row["code"]. "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row["term_no"]. "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

the output of this code like this .
Here every course in one row but I do not want like that.

```
--------------------------
course            term_no
--------------------------
CHEM 101            1
-------------------------
ENGL 101            1
-------------------------
MATH 101            2
--------------------------
PE 101              2
```

how I can make the code do not separate courses that have the same term_no.
I want the the output like this

```
--------------------------
course            term_no
--------------------------
CHEM 101            1
ENGL 101            
-------------------------
MATH 101            2
PE 101
```

Comment: You mean you want to group all courses with the same term_no together?

Comment: Probably gonna want to first start by making an array ;)

Comment: yes ,I want to group all courses with the same term_no together

Comment: I think you should start by putting an ORDER BY in the sql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an array of String where each cell of it holds all the courses in the same term_no that matches the cell id.

Try this out insead of your current while loop:

```
$str = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $str[$row['term_no']] += ",".$row['code'];
}
foreach ($str as $key => $value)
{

   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $value. "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $key. "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
```

EDIT: I changed the code abit try it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here`s how I would do this:

I`d alter your sql command to group and concat results that had the same value of term_no.

```
SELECT group_concat(c.course), dp.term_no FROM `degree_plan` as dp LEFT JOIN courses as c ON
degree_plan.course_number=courses.course_number
where major='COE'
GROUP BY dp.term_no
```

Once done that, I would recover the data concatenated and separated by `,`. Having that, I could do `preg_replace('/,/' , '<br>', $row["code"])` to replace each `,` by '`<br>`OR I could explode the desired value on the iteration ( `explode(",", $value)` ) , create an array and do what I want to do with that.

Note that since I don`t know the exact structure of your DB, I assumed that the table course holds the name of the course. Make the necessary adjustments.